# "Run Time error 9 : subscript out of range" when copying

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy values from one sheet to another and getting this error

> "Run Time error 9 : subscript out of range"

when I run the code below.

```
Sub updatemultiple()
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\akpeko.zigah\Documents\EDC\DESTINATION.xlsm")
Range("B2:F2").Copy
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range("B2:F2")
End Sub
```

Any help? I'm stuck.

Comment: which line is it erroring on?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of unanswered parentage questions to your workbook/worksheet/cell references but if you are pasting into the same workbook as the one containing the code then something like this should work.

```
Sub updatemultiple()

    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\akpeko.zigah\Documents\EDC\DESTINATION.xlsm")
    Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=THISWORKBOOK.Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range("B2")
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

The problems start with how you are determining the currently active worksheet when you open the external workbook. If it was opened, the active worksheet changed then closed byt another person or process then when you opened it it is going to copy the wrong cells. If the destination worksheet is not contained in the workbook containing the code then the destination is an ambiguous reference that depends upon the current state of the application environment.

A short rewrite of your code (with some made-up references thrown in) might be like the following.

```
Sub updatemultiple()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\akpeko.zigah\Documents\EDC\DESTINATION.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range("B2:F2")
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

In short, be as explicit as you can by defining the workbook, worksheet and cell references for each side of every operation. Relying on 'what is active' can only lead to trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly, it seems to me that you have the code in one file. When you execute the code, it opens the DESTINATION.xlsm file, copy the cells, close the DESTINATION.xlsm file, then paste the data in the active sheet of the original file that contains the code.

I don't know what data you're copying, but when you copy (manually, not in code) a lot of data from an excel file and then you close it, you get a warning:

> There is a large amount of information on the Clipboard. Do you want to be able to paste this information to another program later?

For that reason, I recommend you to paste your copied cells first, and then close the file you're copying from.